NBG, ZFC+I, and Global Choice
In Shulman's 2008 paper 'Set Theory for Category Theory', he includes amongst the axioms of $\sf NBG$ the axiom of limitation of size. Being well known to imply the axiom of global choice, it seems to me that since $\sf ZFC+I$ doesn't imply global choice, this should be inconsistent with his later remark that $\sf ZFC+I$ has a model of $\sf NBG$ given by $V_{\kappa}$ for the sets, and $\operatorname{Def}(V_{\kappa})$ for the proper classes. I'm sure there is something here I don't quite understand, I would greatly appreciate some clarification.

That later remark does not say that ZFC+I implies global choice; it says that it provides a model for global choice. A well-order of $V_\kappa$ in the universe will feel like a global well-order if you think $V_\kappa$ is the whole universe.

Care is needed here.
It is true that $\sf ZFC+I$ implies the consistency of $\sf NBG$. And it is true that $\sf ZFC+I$ does not prove Global Choice.
However, when we talk about consistency statements, namely "Theory $T$ proves that theory $S$ has a model", it is a weaker condition. Similarly, $\sf ZF+DC+LM$ (here $\sf LM$ stands for "every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable") proves the consistency of $\sf ZFC$, even if it refutes the Axiom of Choice.
So, what we are really saying here is that there is a model of $\sf NBG$ in which there is a Global Choice function. And since the model is a set in our universe of $\sf ZFC+I$, a choice function on the model can, potentially, be a good candidate for being a Global Choice function.
Nevertheless, the statement you seem to refer to is itself wrong. It is certainly consistent that inside $\operatorname{Def}(V_\kappa)$ there are no well-orders of $V_\kappa$. But it is true that we can find other ways around this. We can take $V_{\kappa+1}$ or we can restrict to $L_\kappa$ and $L_{\kappa+1}=\operatorname{Def}(L_\kappa)$, for our model of $\sf NBG$.

Thanks for your answer! I'm still unclear on whether or not you're saying that inside $V_{\kappa+1}$, there is a well-ordering of $V_{\kappa}$? If so, how would one prove this? Also I'm unfamiliar with the $L_{\kappa}$ notation?

Yes. That is what I'm saying. $V_{\kappa+1}$ is the set of all the subsets of $V_\kappa$, and since $V_\kappa\times V_\kappa\subseteq V_\kappa$, it also contains all the functions and relations on $V_\kappa$. Apply the $\sf C$ in your $\sf ZFC$ and you're done. As for the $L$ notation, this is Gödel's constructible universe which is constructed by taking the definable power set instead of the full power set at each stage. If you're unfamiliar with that, feel free to ignore it, consider it a blackbox, or learn more set theory to be more familiar with it! :-)

What resources on set theory would you recommend to become more familiar with these topics?

Depending on your preexisting knowledge, Jech might be good. Or Enderton. Or Just & Weese. You can take a look on my website, there are lecture notes in set theory which briefly touch on $L$. After reading those, Jech would probably be a suitable option.

Thanks! Could you also offer a proof of the consistency of $\operatorname{Def}(V_{\kappa})$ with not containing a well-ordering of $V_{\kappa}$?

@Noah: You can find it, in a nutshell, in https://mathoverflow.net/q/110799/7206, with the added step that this time we do this forcing over $V_\kappa$, so it's not a class forcing from out perspective.

Thanks for pointing out that mistake.  If and when I revise the note I'll fix it.  Is there a natural subset of $V_{\kappa+1}$ that we could take as the classes to obtain a model of NBG that isn't a model of Morse-Kelley?  E.g. could we use $\mathrm{Def}(V_\kappa \cup {x})$ where $x$ is some fixed well-ordering of $V_\kappa$?

@Mike: That should work. I'd say you probably also want to make sure that your well-ordering is not "too long". Since there will only be $\kappa$ many ordinals definable from $V_\kappa$, but $\kappa^+$ ways to well-order it, if you picked a well-ordering which is "too long" you might run into some non-obvious problems (although, again, I don't know enough off-hand to say that's definitely the case). But picking a well-ordering that is amenable is probably enough. Namely, you want $x\cap V_\alpha$ to be a well-ordering of $V_\alpha$ for all $\alpha<\kappa$.

@MikeShulman Thank you both for the responses! Has been very illuminating.

Coincidentally, here's a blog post today by @JoelDavidHamkins proving that whenever $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC (a much weaker condition than being inaccessible), there is a subset of $V_{\kappa+1}$ that extends it to a model of NBG.  If I understand correctly, he indeed uses $\mathrm{Def}(V_\kappa \cup {x})$ for some well-ordering $x$ of $V_\kappa$, but he uses class forcing to construct a particularly good such $x$.  (I don't quite follow why the good properties are needed.)

@Mike: Suppose that I picked a well order whose first $\omega$ segment is actually a cofinal sequence of ordinals. This would break Replacement on sets, so you can't have that. The idea to add a generic well-order is to ensure this sort of problem doesn't happen.

Mike and Asaf, yes, that is right. Except that the argument isn't "adding" the generic well order $\leq$ of $V_\kappa$ by forcing over $V$ to add it in the usual forcing manner, but rather proving that there is already in $V$ such an order that is $\text{Def}(V_\kappa)$-generic, and this is enough to get NBG in $\langle V_\kappa,\in,\leq\rangle$, just in in the usual conservativity argument for NBG over ZFC. So we can freely add a global choice order to any worldly cardinal and preserve NBG.

@Joel: Your argument in the blog post kinda reminds me of François' answer on my [quite] old question. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151234/can-there-be-only-one-uncountable-transitive-model-of-zfc, not the same, of course, but kind of a flavour of "here's a case we can prove the Rasioa–Sikorski lemma for".

Yes, I see the certain affinity—thanks for the link. One difference, however, is that $\kappa$ is regular in his argument, whereas the difficulty of the worldly case is that they are singular in the hard case. This is why the method of working along the $\Sigma_n$-correct cardinal sequence is used.

@Joel: Yes, there are different reasons as to why this works.

@Joel and Asaf, thanks!  Where can I read about why genericity ensures this sort of problem doesn't happen?  The blog post simply references "the usual forcing argument".

Also, is genericity also necessary in the case when $\kappa$ is inaccessible?

Genericity is not needed when $\kappa$ is inaccessible, since in this case you can use the full second-order part $V_{\kappa+1}$, and you'll therefore get not just GBC but fully Kelley-Morse set theory, which allows quantification over classes in the comprehension scheme.

I'm not sure what the best reference is for the forcing argument. The basic fact is that GBC with global choice is conservative over ZFC. To see this, if you have any ZFC model, then it is easy to see that you get GB+AC in the second-order structure by allowing all definable classes (with parameters). The only thing remaining is global choice, which might not hold if there is no definable global well order. But the forcing P with set-sized condition well ordering an initial segment is class forcing adding a global well order. This forcing notion is very mild, since it adds no sets.

Thus, one need only check that GBC holds in the forcing extension, where the new classes are obtained by old classes that are names. These are the same as classes that are definable from the new well order. I'll try to find a reference.

Here is a link to reviews of Felgner 1971 and a paper of Mostowski, which give the argument: https://doi.org/10.2307/2272004. But I think the argument is now quite commonly given by just explaining how the forcing goes. Since the forcing adds no sets at all, it is amongst the easy kinds of class forcing. I'm not sure if the argument is in Jech. Solovay says on FOM (here: https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2010-April/014533.html) that the result is due to many people, including himself, and Jensen.
